# Veil Installation Stuck at wine

Tags: ruby, pywin32, wine, winelib

i am trying to install veil framework by

```
./setup.sh --force
```

but installation stuck when wine start. i am gonna show you some code

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
[ERROR] Failed with installing wine (2): 0

[*] [ALERT]: Existing Veil Wine environment detected at: /var/lib/veil/wine

```
 Do you want to nuke it? ([y]es/[N]o): y
```

[*] Deleting existing Veil Wine environment...

[*] Creating new Veil Wine environment in: /var/lib/veil/wine

[*] Initializing Veil's Wine environment...

 **[ERROR] Failed to install (Wine) Python 3.4.4... Exit code: 137**

[*] Installing (Wine) Python dependencies...

[*] Installing (Wine) Python's pywin32-220.win32-py3.4.exe...

**[ERROR] Failed to install pywin32-220.win32-py3.4.exe... Exit code: 123**

[*] Installing (Wine) Python's pycrypto-2.6.1.win32-py3.4.exe...

**[ERROR] Failed to install pycrypto-2.6.1.win32-py3.4.exe... Exit code: 123**

[*] Installing (OS) Python's PyInstaller (via TAR)

wine: cannot find '/var/lib/veil/wine/drive_c/Python34/python.exe'
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine: cannot find '/var/lib/veil/wine/drive_c/Python34/python.exe'

[*] Finished (Wine + OS) Python dependencies installation

[*] Initializing (Wine) Ruby installation...

[*] Installing (Wine) Ruby & dependencies

it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"

 **[ERROR] Failed to install (Wine) Ruby.exe... Exit code: 123**

[*] Installing (Wine) Ruby OCRA gem...

it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"

**[ERROR] Failed to run (wine) Ruby OCRA.. Exit code: 49**

[*] Extracting (Wine) Ruby dependencies...

[*] Installing (Wine) AutoIT

[*]  Next -> Next -> Next -> Finished! ...Overwrite if prompt (use default values)

it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
002b:err:module:__wine_process_init L"Z:\var\lib\veil\setup-dependencies\autoit-v3-setup.exe" not supported on this system

 **[ERROR] Failed to run (wine) AutoIT.. Exit code: 123**

[*] Finished AutoIT installation

[*] Updating Veil configuration...

[*] Finished Veil configuration...

[*] Finished environment checks

  
*[ERROR] There was issues installing the following:*

**Failed with installing wine (2): 0  

Failed to install (Wine) Python 3.4.4... Exit code: 137  

Failed to install pywin32-220.win32-py3.4.exe... Exit code: 123  

Failed to install pycrypto-2.6.1.win32-py3.4.exe... Exit code: 123  

Failed to install (Wine) Ruby.exe... Exit code: 123  

Failed to run (wine) Ruby OCRA.. Exit code: 49  

Failed to run (wine) AutoIT.. Exit code: 123**

[I] If you have any errors running Veil, run: './Veil.py --setup' and select the nuke the wine folder option

[I] Done!

 
 should i install these error packages externally or not ?? any suggestion and solution

Answer (score 2):

1-delete all the files of the veil install from scratch

2-update kali linux

```
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt dist-upgrade`
```

3- try these codes

`pip3 uninstall pycrypto`

`pip3 install pycryptodome`

`python3 Veil.py`

not: I was using kali 2020.3 and step 3 worked for me, then I switched to 2021.1 and installed it without any difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

run

> apt-get install wine32

> apt-get install pip

> apt-get install ruby-full

check if ruby already installed or not use ***which ruby***, if installed it will be displaying path.
*

> apt-get update

> apt-get upgrade

> apt-get dist-upgrade

run all these in *root* terminal.